# Why is a compact topological space must be limit point compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Recently I have been studying topology, and I am confused about the definition of limit point compactness.

The definition of limit point compactness I have learnt is the following:

> **Limit Point Compactness**: A topological space *(X,T)* is **limit point compact** if every infinite subset of *X* has a limit point in *X*.

I am just wondering is it possible for the set *X* to have an infinite subset if the set *X* itself is finite? If not, then why does the following theorem hold when the set *X* has finite elements:

> If a topological space (*X*, *T*) is compact, then it is limit point compact.

Comment: Any finite space is limit point compact, by [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: If there are no infinite subsets, then all zero of those infinite subsets have a limit point.

Comment: Thanks, Anne and Vercassivelaunos, your comments make sense. Now I understood. So here, the antecedent should be "if every infinite subset of X has a limit point in X" and it is not satisfied.

Comment: When $X$ is finite, the statement "every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point" **is** satisfied.

Comment: Hi @AndreasBlass, in what sense is this statement satisfied if *X* is finite?

Comment: When $X$ is finite, it has no infinite subset. So any statement of the form "every infinite subset of $X$ has such-and-such property" is vacuously true (as pointed out in the earlier comment by @AnneBauval).

Comment: @AndreasBlass It makes sense. Cheers.